# Make inconsistent assumptions over interface

Tags: makefile, ocaml

I want to optimise the compilation time of my `makefile`. One problem that waists my time is, after modifying one single file, `make` returns for instance,

```
File "frontend/parser_e.ml", line 1:
Error: The files expression/rc.cmi and frontend/gen/lexer_ref.cmi
       make inconsistent assumptions over interface Utility
make: *** [frontend/parser_e.cmx] Error 2
rm frontend/parser_name.ml
```

Note that the files in trouble may change, but it happens quite often. What I have to do is `make clean` and then `make`, as a consequence it is not an incremental build and takes time.

So does anyone know what I should check in my `makefile` to reduce the chance of having this kind of error?

**Edit 1:**

Actually, all my ml-related files are in depth `1`, except `frontend/gen/*`, which are in depth 2. Following the answer of @camlspotter, I modified a little bit the `ocamldep` part of my `makefile`. Now it looks like follows:

```
DIRS= -I frontend -I frontend/gen -I lib ...

depend: $(AUTOGEN)
        # ocamldep -native $(DIRS) */*.ml */*.mli > depend # this is what was written before, I don't hink it is correct
        ocamldep -native $(DIRS) *.ml *.mli > depend
```

As a consequence, `make` following another `make` gives immediately an inconsistence error.

One remark is I don't have `AUTOGEN`, is it normal?

Another remark is that `make depend` generates a `depend` that has 0 character, is it normal?

**Edit 2:**

I modified `depend:` by following `Makefile` of OCaml source code:

```
beforedepend:: */*.ml

depend: beforedepend
    (for d in \
    frontend frontend/gen lib ... ; \
    do ocamldep $(DIRS) $$d/*.mli $$d/*.ml; \
    done) > depend
```

I have actually around 20 folders, each has 1-5 ml files. This time, `make` rangs over `for d in ...`, and does not want to stop. But if I remove 3-4 folders, it succeeds to create a `depend` after several seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Makefile does not cover all the necessary dependencies between modules.

The meaning of

```
File "frontend/parser_e.ml", line 1:
Error: The files expression/rc.cmi and frontend/gen/lexer_ref.cmi
       make inconsistent assumptions over interface Utility
```

is:

- `frontend/parser_e.ml` depends on `expression/rc.ml` and `frontend/gen/lexer_ref.ml`
- Both `expression/rc.ml` and `frontend/gen/lexer_ref.ml` use module named `Utility`
- `expression/rc.ml` and `frontend/gen/lexer_ref.ml` must agree with the type (interface) of `Utility`, but did not.

I think of two possibilities to cause this state:

- There may be two different `utility.ml`, for example `dir_a/utility.ml` and `dir_b/utility.ml`.  OCaml does not allow linking modules with the same name.   You can workaround this using packed modules (see `-pack` compiler option).  Your case is not this.
- The both modules use the same `utility.ml` but the dependencies may not be perfectly known to your Makefile.  This is your case.

A possible scenario of the second case is:

- You have modified `utility.ml` or `utility.mli` and its interface (`.cmi` file) has been changed.
- One of `expression/rc.ml` and `frontend/gen/lexer_ref.ml` is recompiled against this new interface of `Utility`, but the other IS NOT, since the dependency is not known.
- The compiler has found the inconsistency between the two modules when they are used together in `frontend/parser_e.ml`.

For fix, you have to run `ocamldep` to capture all the necessary module dependencies and inform it to `make`.  Note that:

- Give proper options and arguments.  Since you work with nested directories, you need `-I` option several times.
- Make sure that the auto-generated `.ml` and `.mli` files are really generated before `ocamldep` runs.  Since you seem to have `.mly` and `.mll` files and you have the issue around them, I suspect you miss something around here.

A good example of the dependency analysis of OCaml modules is found at OCaml compiler source code itself.  It is good to check around its lines with `beforedepend`, `depend` and `include .depend`.

---

General hints:

- Add `include .depend` to your Makefile and capture all the module dependencies into this `.depend` file, using `ocamldep`
- Note that all the `.ml` and `.mli` files of your project must be scanned by `ocamldep`.  Do not forget to add `-I` options properly or it misses some dependencies.
- Before running `ocamldep`, make sure auto-generated `.ml` and `.mli` files such as the output of `.mly` and `.mll` are generated.  Or it misses some dependencies.

Typical Makefile looks like:

```
beforedepend:: x.ml

x.ml: x.mly
  ocamlyacc x.mly

beforedepend:: y.ml

y.ml: y.mll
  ocamllex y.mll

depend: beforedepend
  ocamldep -I <dir1> -I <dir2> <all the ml and mli paths> > .depend

include .depend
```

Comment: Why you ask ocamldep to scan *.ml and *.mli only though your source files are all in some directories?  And regarding of your module names I guess you use mly and mll which mean that you have some AUTOGEN'ed files.  Please check the document ocamldep and read the example I gave you.

Comment: I really don't know what `beforedepend` is used for... I have updated the OP, could you take a look? Also, I do have mly and mll...

Comment: Without the whole code tree I really have no idea whether that code works or not.  Only I can give you is general knowledge.